# Find positive integers $n$ such that the derivative of $f(z)=(z-1)^nB(z)$ is bounded in $U$, where $B$ is a Blaschke product with zeros on $(0,1)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, blaschke-products

Suppose that $B$ is a Blaschke product with zeros on $(0,1)$. Find all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that  the derivative of $f(z)=(z-1)^nB(z)$ is bounded in $U$. My thoughts: My guess is that it is true for all $n \ge 1$. I take the derivative directly
\begin{equation*}
f'(z)=n(z-1)^{n-1}B(z)+(z-1)^nB'(z).
\end{equation*} Now $n(z-1)^{n-1}B(z)$ is clearly bounded in $U$, but I cannot show that $B'(z)$ is also bounded in $U$. Any hints?

Comment: Is your question about finite or infinite Blaschke products?

Comment: @ Martin R, I think the finite case is easy. The problem is the infinite case.

Comment: finite Blaschke products $B$ are analytic on a disc with radius higher than $1$ so obviously all the derivatives of $B$ are bounded because they are continuous on the closed unit disc

Comment: @ Conrad, Yes, but how is an infinite Blaschke product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need $n \ge 2$ but I do not know an easy proof of necessity without some general Hardy space theory; for sufficiency, it is easy since if $B=\Pi{\frac{|z_n|(z_n-z)}{z_n(1-\bar z_n z)}}$, and $B_n$ is the Blaschke product where we omit the $n$ term, we immediately get the formula (with normal convergence on the open unit disc):

$B'(z)=-\sum{\frac{|z_n|(1-|z_n|^2)}{z_n(1-\bar z_n z)^2}B_n(z)}$

But now $|B_n(z)| <1$ and if $z_n=r_n>0$ real we have $|1-r_nz|^2 \ge C^2|1-z|^2, (C=\min (|r_n| \ne 0 >0)$ for any $|z|<1$, hence $|B'(z)| \le \frac{1}{C^2}\frac{\sum(1-|z_n|^2)}{|1-z|^2}$ and the Blaschke condition is precisely that the numerator is convergent so we get $|1-z|^2|B'(z)| \le  M$

On the other hand it is a theorem that if we call the individual factors $b_n(z)$ and we define as usual, (for $p>0$), $||B'||_p=\sup_{r<1}(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}{|B'(re^{it})|^pdt})^{\frac{1}{p}}$, we have $||B'||_p \ge \sum ||b_n'||_p$ (which is non-trivial obviously only when $||B'||_p < \infty$ and actually with a little more work we get equality so LHS and RHS are finite or infinite at the same time)

But now it is an easy exercise to show that $||b_n'||_{\frac{1}{2}} \ge C(1-r_n)\log^2(1-r_n)$, so in particular if $\sum{(1-r_n)\log^2(1-r_n)} =\infty$ we cannot have $||B'||_{\frac{1}{2}} <\infty$. However $||\frac{1}{1-z}||_{\frac{1}{2}}$ is clearly finite so $(1-z)B'$ cannot be bounded.

Taking $r_n=1-\frac{1}{n \log^2 n}, n \ge 2$ we obviously satisfy the Blaschke convergence condition, but $(1-r_n)\log^2(1-r_n)$ ~$\frac{1}{n}$, so for the corresponding $||B'||_{\frac{1}{2}} =\infty$, hence $(z-1)B'$ cannot be bounded

Comment: This is a very clear solution. So my conjecture is wrong. One more question: Why do we have $|1-r_nz|^2 \ge C^2|1-z|^2$? Thanks very much!

Comment: If $a>1$, it is easy to see geometrically that $|a-z|>|1-z|, |z| \le 1$ or you can start from $(a+1)>2|z|\cos \theta$ multiply by $a-1$ etc if you want an algebraic proof; but this is equivalent to $|1-rz| > r|1-z|, r=\frac{1}{a}$ so one can take $C=\min r_n, r_n \ne 0$ as there are only finitely many possible $r_n=0$ even if we allow them; note that it is crucial that $r_n$ real positive as there are examples of Blaschke products with zeroes that accumulate only at $1$ still, but for which $B'$ is highly unbounded so for example no power $k$ makes $(z-1)^kB'$ bounded